# How to add custom git command to zsh completion?

Tags: git, zsh-completion

I've read a few guides on zsh completion, but I am still confused. In our development environment we have a custom Git command called `git new-branch`. I'd like zsh to auto-complete it for me after typing just `git ne` and a <kbd>Tab</kbd>. How can I do that?

Comment: 2 years later,this will be possible with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), which will better take into account `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668739/6309)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default git completion [is extendible](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/cb26725d40a9104ee08e3ca6ff9661890eca8a65/Completion/Unix/Command/_git):

> Say you got your own git sub-commands (git will run a program `git-foo'
>   when you run "git foo") and you want "git f" to complete that sub
>   commands name for you. You can make that sub-command known to the completion
>   via the user-command style:
>
> ```
> % zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' user-commands foo:'description for foo'
> ```
>
> `user-commands' is a list style, so you can add any number of programs there.
>   The :description part is optional, so you could add all git-* programs from
>   your $path like this:
>
> ```
> % zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' user-commands ${${(M)${(k)commands}:#git-*}/git-/}
> ```

That is, it suffices to add

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' user-commands new-branch:'custom new branch function'
```

to your `zshrc`.

If you would like to handle parameters to your custom command as well, then it is a better solution to use a custom compdef file. The file referenced above has some details on that as well: Just create a standard definition file defining a `git-<yourcommand>` function, the default git completion will use it automatically when needed.

Answer (score 3):

With Git 2.18 (q2 2018), you have a new possibility, which applies not just for zsh: The command line completion mechanism (in `contrib/`) has learned to load
a custom completion file for "`git $command`" where `$command` is a
custom "`git-$command`" that the end user has on the $PATH when using
newer version of bash.

See [commit 085e2ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/085e2ee0e62a97c2dc56d4a6baf3e03ce124bba9) (29 Apr 2018) by [Florian Gamböck (`FloGa`)](https://github.com/FloGa).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fb3a0ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb3a0cabf23ccd1d4ae3fead2c5b478930630822), 23 May 2018)</sup>

> ### completion: load completion file for external subcommand
>
> Adding external subcommands to Git is as easy as to put an executable
>   file `git-foo` into `PATH`.
>   Packaging such subcommands for a Linux distribution can be achieved by unpacking the executable into `/usr/bin` of the user's system.
>   **Adding system-wide completion scripts for new subcommands, however, can be a bit tricky.**
>
> Since bash-completion started to use dynamical loading of completion
>   scripts since v1.90 (preview of v2.0), it is no longer sufficient to
>   drop a completion script of a subcommand into the standard completions
>   path, `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, since this script will not
>   be loaded if called as a `git subcommand`.
>
> For example, look at https://bugs.gentoo.org/544722.
>   To give a short summary: The popular `git-flow subcommand` provides a completion script, which gets installed as `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git-flow`.
>
> If you now type into a Bash shell:
>
> ```
> git flow <TAB>
> ```
>
> You will not get any completions, because bash-completion only loads
>   completions for git and git has no idea that git-flow is defined in
>   another file.
>   You have to load this script manually or trigger the
>   dynamic loader with:
>
> ```
> `git-flow <TAB>` # Please notice the dash instead of whitespace
> ```
>
> This will not complete anything either, because it only defines a Bash
>   function, without generating completions.
>   But now the correct completion script has been loaded and the first command can use the completions.
>
> So, **the goal is now to teach the git completion script to consider the
>   possibility of external completion scripts for subcommands**, but of
>   course without breaking current workflows.

How? This is what Git 2.18 proposes:

> I think the easiest method is to use a function that was defined by
>   `bash-completion` v1.90, namely `_completion_loader`.
>   It will take care of loading the correct script if present.
>   Afterwards, the git completion script behaves as usual.
>
> `_completion_loader` was introduced in [commit 20c05b43](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/commit/20c05b43b6e44be8ae3c5025a77eca62a48c5a62) of [`scop/bash-completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) (the programmable completion functions for bash) back in 2011, so it should be available in even older LTS distributions.
>   This function searches for external completion scripts not only in the default path `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, but also in the user's home
>   directory via `$XDG_DATA_HOME` and in a user specified directory via
>   `$BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR`.

---

[univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341730/univerio) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725102/how-to-add-custom-git-command-to-zsh-completion/50668739?noredirect=1#comment93858145_50668739):

> It turns out that there are two different completion functions:
>
> - One [ships with zsh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/50f8fa972c3795a115e7faff0b4c140b40eab5f0/Completion/Unix/Command/_git), and
> - the other ships with Git.

univerio adds:

> - The zsh-provided function is the default on Debian (and Ubuntu, Mint, etc), and
> - the git-provided function is the default on homebrew-installed git on macOS.
>
> Super confusing. Not sure which one is better.
>
> This particular answer works only for the git-provided function, while the accepted answer works only for the zsh-provided function.

Comment: I upgraded to git 2.19.1 hoping to take advantage of this, but I must be missing something as my custom git-foo command does not auto complete.

Comment: @rtaft Strange, on which environment are you trying this? Linux? Windows, Mac?

Comment: I tried Mint 18.3 first, then tried Mint 19.0.  I upgraded both boxes to use 2.19.1

Comment: @rtaft I looked into this. It turns out that there are two different completion functions. One ships with [zsh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/50f8fa972c3795a115e7faff0b4c140b40eab5f0/Completion/Unix/Command/_git), and the other ships with [git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a1598010f775d82b5adf12c29d0f5bc9b41434c6/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh). The zsh-provided function is the default on Debian (and Ubuntu, Mint, etc), and the git-provided function is the default on homebrew-installed git on macOS. Super confusing. Not sure which one is better.

Comment: I should also add that this particular answer works *only* for the git-provided function, while the accepted answer works *only* for the zsh-provided function.

Comment: @univerio Very interesting feedback, than you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.