# ZSH: Completion aliases for subcommands, e.g. "compdef foo='git log'"

Tags: git, zsh, completion

I have a bunch of tools that pass all arguments to an internal invocation of e.g. "git log".  A trivial example might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
git log --since='1 year ago' "$@"
```

I know that I can have completion aliases by doing e.g.:

```
compdef myscript=grep
```

However, it's not clear how to do this for subcommands like `git log`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom git command to zsh completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725102/how-to-add-custom-git-command-to-zsh-completion)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzsh%5D+git+subcommand+completion

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution which will work with aliases, but not with functions or scripts. In your case, with `git log`, it is enough.

1. Create an alias.
   `mygitlog="git log --since='1 year ago'"`
2. Enable **compinit** for zsh completion in your **.zshrc**.
   `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`
3. Disable **completealiases** option, which is preventing aliases from being internally substituted before completion is attempted.
   `unset completealiases`

After typing `mygitlog` and pressing `Tab` twice in Git repository, zsh will suggest you commits and tags that were made in the last year.